# Why is Ezri's mother confused about her daughter using the symbiote's name?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9

In S7E11 Ezri contacts her mother to ask her to help look for Chief O'Brien.

Her mother seems confused about Ezri using the symbiote name, Dax, as her surname, if you will.

Her mother is Trill, surely she's knows about this?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The [original script](https://www.st-minutiae.com/resources/scripts/561.txt) gives us a little more context. Ezri was clearly having difficulty integrating her new persona (as Dax) with her old persona (as Ezri Tigan) when she last spoke to her family, which we can reasonably assume would have caused her mother a great deal of concern. She starts this call by telling her mother that she's more sure of her identity, but then drops in that she's now Ezri ***Dax***, which serves as a reminder that the "*who I am*" isn't Ezri Tigan any more.

Her mother was essentially hoping the whole symbiont thing would just [go away](https://www.verywellmind.com/denial-as-a-defense-mechanism-5114461) and leave her daughter intact. She's put out when she gets another reminder slapped in her face that this isn't the case, hence the awkwardness.

> **EZRI:** *I'm all right. Really. And I'm a lot more sure of who I am than the last time you saw me.*
>
> **YANAS:** *Well, that's a relief.* (wry smile) *I'd hate to have to start calling you Curzon.*
>
> [Ezri smiles a little, but she's clearly uncomfortable.]
>
> **EZRI:** *I... I've been promoted.*
>
> **YANAS:** *Oh?*
>
> **EZRI:** *Lieutenant junior grade Ezri Dax at your service.*
>
> [The name causes Yanas to stiffen slightly.]
>
> **YANAS:** *Ezri... Dax.*
>
> **EZRI:** (awkward) *The symbiont name always replaces the family name of the... new host. It's traditional.*
>
> [Yanas only lets the disappointment show for a second, then she puts on a pleasant expression again.]
>
> **YANAS:** *Of course it is. I haven't been away from Trill that long.*
> (cheerfully)
> *The important thing is you're doing well.*

You might also want to note that the Tigans are a family of Trill who moved to a colony world and have effectively turned their backs on the whole 'joining' thing, so her mother may also be rather discombobulated about finding her daughter returning to a set of traditions that she's explicitly rejected.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you! I had thought all Trill were joined but realised I was incorrect.

Comment: @MrPablo Yeah, this was the plot of another episode where it was revealed that while it's likely possible for any Trill to host a symbiote, there simply aren't nearly enough of them to go around - I think it was only like 5% of them or something.  Which is why they lie and claim that only the best of the best are capable of being a host, and only after years of training.  Ezri was distinctly *not* in that group, she just had the (mis?)fortune to be the only Trill around when the Dax symbiote needed a new host.

Comment: [As you know](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/AsYouKnow), the symbiont name replaces the host surname.

Comment: Upvote for using the word "discombobulated". What a lovely word!